# raising exponential of limit of fractions

Tags: calculus, limits

I am sorry if I failed to get my thought in the easy way. I am thinking to prove following:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{g(x)}} = 0
$$

My own proof goes this way,

$$
m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{g(x)}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{f(x)}f'(x)}{e^{g(x)}g'(x)}\\
m=m\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$

We know $g(x)$ grows much faster, so $m \neq \infty$, and assume $f, g$ have derivatives, so $m=0$ is proved.

But I am not happen about this. Here I assumed both functions have first order derivatives, and I hand waved $m \neq \infty$, which is not rigorous.

Do you have better way to prove this general fact?

Comment: Considering $\large \frac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{g(x)}}=e^{f(x)-g(x)}$, I doubt that the implication is true in general. If $f$ tends to $0$ and $g$ tends to , lets say, $1$, don't we have a counterexample then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false, even if you assume smoothness. Take $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 1$, and $m = 1/e \ne 0$.

---

Also, the proof breaks down for other reasons. The fact that $\lim f/g = 0$ doesn't imply that $\lim f'/g' = 0$. The limit may not exist, even for differentiable $f$ and $g$.

Comment: i do get the first part. why the second part is not true, even if I assume differentiability?

Comment: Take something like $g(x) = x \sin x$. The limit of its derivative does not exist.

Comment: you are perfectly correct.